# Identify rars o zips with passwords

Tags: winrar

I make scripts with Autohotkey. One of my hotkeys will check all selected zips or rars and should detect which of them are password protected, so as to isolated or rename them.

Is there any command line with Winrar or with any other tool that can tell me this?

Answer (score 1):

After having had a look at [this](https://supportex.net/blog/2011/08/bash-check-zip-rar-file-password-protection/) blog post, I can suggest you run 7-zip from the command line:

`7z l -slt file.zip` or 
`7z l -slt file.rar`

You will get a list of file properties, including the line:

`Encrypted = -` or `Encrypted = +`

depending on whether the file is password-protected or not. Just check for this line with, e.g.:

`| findstr /c:"Encrypted = +"` in Powershell

`| grep "Encrypted = +"` in Bash ([Cygwin](https://www.cygwin.com/), [wsl](https://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/commandline/wsl/about) or [Git-Bash](https://git-for-windows.github.io/))